# Calculate a running sum in MySQL that increments when a field = 1 and decrements by 1 when that same field = 0

Tags: mysql

Hello I am new to MySQL and I am having trouble creating the following MySQL Query.  I have a table that looks like this:

```
id   TestCase   PassFail
1     tc_a          1
2     tc_b          0
3     tc_c          1
4     tc_a          0
5     tc_c          1
6     tc_b          1
7     tc_a          1
8     tc_a          1
```

I want to write a query that creates a table that is a running sum of the PassFail field.  This field should increment by 1 whenever a unique test case first passes or toggles between fail and pass and decrement by 1 whenever a test case toggles between pass and fail.  The sum should not change when the new status of a test case remains the same. The output table for my example should look like:

```
id    TestCase PassFail passSum    note (not in output table)
1      tc_a       1         1      first pass for tc_a, increment by 1 
2      tc_b       0         1      fail for tc_b, no change 
3      tc_c       1         2      first pass for tc_c, increment by 1
4      tc_a       0         1      toggled pass to fail tc_a, decrement by 1
5      tc_c       1         1      no change for tc_c, no change
6      tc_b       1         2      toggled fail to pass tc_b, increment by 1
7      tc_a       1         3      toggled fail to pass tc_a, increment by 1
8      tc_a       1         3      no change for tc_a, no change
```

I was able to create a running total that increments whenever a new test case passes by using DISTINCT but I can't figure out how to get it to decrement when that unique test case fails.  Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated!

Comment: which version of mysql are you on?

Comment: Why isn't row 2 equal to 0?

Comment: MySQL version 5.7.21.  Also I just edited my original post hopefully it is more clear now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your edit helps tremendously.

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t(id int,  TestCase varchar(10),   PassFail int);
insert into t values
(1  ,   'tc_a' ,         1),
(2  ,   'tc_b' ,         0),
(3  ,   'tc_c' ,         1),
(4  ,   'tc_a' ,         0),
(5  ,   'tc_c' ,         1),
(6  ,   'tc_b' ,         1),
(7  ,   'tc_a' ,         1),
(8  ,   'tc_a' ,         1);
```

In the sub query s below I work out a combined status for each test case using a sub query with a limit clause. The outer query then uses a variable to calculate passsum based on the combined status. I think only 01 and 10 are of interest and I have not tested extensively but the result does match your desired output.

```
select s.id,s.testcase,s.passfail,s.combined,
         case 
                when combined = 01 then @passsum:=@passsum + 1
                when combined = 10 then @passsum:=@passsum - 1
                else @passsum:=@passsum
         end passsum
from
(
select t.ID,t.testcase,t.passfail,
         concat (
             case
             when (select passfail from t t1 where t1.testcase = t.testcase and t1.id < t. id order by t1.ID limit 1) is null then 0
           else (select passfail from t t1 where t1.testcase = t.testcase and t1.id < t. id order by t1.ID desc limit 1)
         end,
         t.passfail
         ) as combined
from t
order by t.testcase,t.id
) s
cross join (select @passsum:=0) a
order by s.id;

 +------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
| ID   | testcase | passfail | combined | passsum |
+------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
|    1 | tc_a     |        1 | 01       | 1       |
|    2 | tc_b     |        0 | 00       | 1       |
|    3 | tc_c     |        1 | 01       | 2       |
|    4 | tc_a     |        0 | 10       | 1       |
|    5 | tc_c     |        1 | 11       | 1       |
|    6 | tc_b     |        1 | 01       | 2       |
|    7 | tc_a     |        1 | 01       | 3       |
|    8 | tc_a     |        1 | 11       | 3       |
+------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
```

Comment: That worked, thanks so much! I am new to stackoverflow also, is there something I should do to close this issue and/or give you credit?